# Help! I can't see the files and folders that are on the desktop

Tags: unity, 20.04, desktop-icons

I have the same problem, I can't see the files and folders that are on the desktop. I load the start bar with the icons and compiz but I can't see the folders and files on the desktop. How can I fix it? I wrote unity in the terminal and the result was that I don't have unity installed. What happened?
[image]I have Ubuntu 20.4.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 uses gnome as default DE. Current versions of Gnome / gnome-shell don't show desktop icons per default.

Install the Gnome Extension "Desktop Icons" from https://extensions.gnome.org to get desktop icons back to the desktop.

Comment: i don't understand, until yesterday I could see everything.

Comment: Check that the extension is installed and enabled.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ in your bowser...

Comment: How do I install?

Comment: G to the mentioned website, find the "Desktop Icons" extension, if the status is "Off" change it to "On" ... under "Installed Extensions" you can see what is installed, manage / update / disable / remove installed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Open a termial:

Type in the following:

#### To show home folder at Desktop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home true
```

#### To show Recycle bin(aka Trashcan) at Desktop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash true
```

//Regards

Comment: Or just use the `Desktop Icons` GNOME Shell extension, which is installed by default. Enable it, and turn on the two switches found there.